# How do you create a streamlined gui in python using multiple function?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am trying to create a gui which would for example end the program once the user clicks a button, however, since the main portion of the program is located in the main() function, I cannot find a way to to end the program inside another function.
This is my code:

```
import turtle
import random
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox


def main():
    windowScreen = Tk()
    windowScreen.title("Our cinema Application!")
    lbl = Label(windowScreen, text="Welcome to our cinema Application!",font=("Arial bold",50))
    lbl.grid(column=0,row=0)
    btn1 = Button(windowScreen, text="View Available Movie", bg="green", )
    btn1.grid(column=0,row=1)
    btn2 = Button(windowScreen, text="Purchase Tickets", bg="green", command=movie)
    btn2.grid(column=0,row=2)
    btn3 = Button(windowScreen, text="Exit the Application",  bg="red", command=action1, activebackground="white")
    btn3.grid(column=0,row=3)
    windowScreen.mainloop()
    print("Welcome to Dan & Fred's Cinema!")


def action1():
    messagebox.showinfo("Exit Application","Thank you for visiting and come again!")
    mainloop().exitonclick()
    exit()
```

Comment: You need to have `windowScreen` in a global, then you call `windowsScreen.destroy()` to close the main window, which will exit the app.  Note that your `print` statement won't run until the application exits, because `mainloop` won't return.

Answer (score 0):

Your program is almost correct, just remove `mainloop().exitonclick()`.

`exitonclick` is a function of turtle and would be used to close turle window, so it wont have any effect on tkinter window.

You can either make `windowScreen` a global variable (as @Tim Robert suggested) and add `windowScreen.destroy()` in `action1` function or have a nested function to achive the same.

Using nested function, your code would look like this:

```
def main():
    def action1():
        messagebox.showinfo("Exit Application","Thank you for visiting and come again!")
        windowScreen.destroy()
    windowScreen = Tk()
    windowScreen.title("Our cinema Application!")
    btn3 = Button(windowScreen, text="Exit the Application",  bg="red", command=action1, activebackground="white")
    btn3.grid(column=0,row=3)
    windowScreen.mainloop()
```